# Is prompt available in Vte?

Tags: shell, terminal, gtk, vala, vte

I have a shell running in a Vte.Terminal widget (could be bash, zsh, or any other interactive shell), I would like to monitor it so as to know when the prompt is available and a new command can be started.

I can't seem to come up with a consistent method.

Here are the ideas I've thought of so far:

- **Monitor for child process exit.**
  Could work some of the time, but commands that use only built-ins wouldn't spawn a child. (example: "while true; do; echo test; done;") Also When a command is started in background the prompt would be available before the child exited.
- **Watch for prompt string in Vte output.**
  Two problems: 1. A simple prompt string such as "#>" could easily be outputted by some script and give a false positive. 2. Knowing what the prompt string is, is problematic.

Any other ideas or a way to get one of the above working?

### What my purpose is.

I'm working on a terminal emulator and would like to change the icon based on whether the prompt is available. Also I am attempting to allow commands to be 'queued' to run when next possible.

Comment: What if the command is still running *and* the prompt is available?

Comment: I just want to know when a new command can be started. So when the prompt is available I guess.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Are you trying to run a series of interactive commands or are you trying to monitor the state of a shell? Programs like `tmux` and `screen`, expect specific escape codes for the shell/program to communicate with the containing terminal.

Comment: @apmasell Both. I've edited to provide more details.